# Log user in on subdomain with Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm building a web app with Django, using django-tenant-schemas. I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- User registers on the main domain, example.com
- In the background, a tenant is created at test.example.com and a user for this tenant
- The user is redirected to his new subdomain, test.example, **and is automatically logged in**

I can't figure out how to log the user in. This is the registration view:

```
def register(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        webshop = Tenant()
        webshop.domain_url = form.cleaned_data['name'] + '.localhost'
        webshop.schema_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        webshop.save()

        with schema_context(form.cleaned_data['name']):
            f = form.cleaned_data
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(f['email'], f['password'], f['user_name'])
            send_registration_confirmation(user, form.cleaned_data['name'])

        redirect = 'http://' + form.cleaned_data['name'] + '.localhost:8000'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)

  else:
    form = RegistrationForm()

return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form,})
```

If I use the `authenticate` and `login` functions from Django, the user gets logged in on the main domain, but not on the subdomain.

Comment: Have you tried setting ```SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=".example.com" ``` in your settings.py file?

Comment: I've considered doing this, but as I understand it this would mean the session gets shared across all subdomains? This is not what I want, since a user should only be able to log in on his own subdomain.

Comment: @Axel did you figured out what was a problem here? I have the same issue

Comment: @user9192656 No I did not. In the end we moved away from one subdomain per tenant, to one subdomain 'app.example.com' and tenant selection based on the authentication token in the requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Axel
Do you mean a solution - one database, one schema?
Did you write your own solution to this, with multi tenant apps approch?
Or, just a normal application, but the accounts are separated by permissions?